# Compile a TypeScript String to a Javascript String programmatically

Tags: javascript, compilation, typescript

Is there a way to compile a **String** containing TypeScript to its JavaScript **String** equivalent ?

For instance, in Coffeescript (and LiveScript, coco etc) its a (simplified) one-liner:

`jsCompiledCode = require('coffee-script').compile('do -> console.log "Hello world"', {bare:true});`

Can something similar be implemented for TypeScript, preferably without involving the filesystem ? Are there any implications with referencing other modules that would have to be resolved at compile time ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use TypeScript.Api nodejs package : https://npmjs.org/package/typescript.api

In particular check out this function : https://github.com/sinclairzx81/typescript.api#compile

Comment: I was hoping for a no-3rd-party-package solution, to easily use for urequire Resource Converters (urequire.org/resourceconverters.coffee). I see that TypeScript is very opinionated about its modules... There's quite a bit of work to support cross nodejs/AMD/typescript in uRequire I guess...

Answer (score 17):

You can use the `transpileModule()` method that comes with TypeScript.

```
$ npm install typescript
```

```
// compile.ts

import * as ts from "typescript";

function tsCompile(source: string, options: ts.TranspileOptions = null): string {
    // Default options -- you could also perform a merge, or use the project tsconfig.json
    if (null === options) {
        options = { compilerOptions: { module: ts.ModuleKind.CommonJS }};
    }
    return ts.transpileModule(source, options).outputText;
}

// Make sure it works
const source = "let foo: string  = 'bar'";

let result = tsCompile(source);

console.log(result); // var foo = 'bar';
```

When compiling this you will need the tsconfig `moduleResolution` set to `"Node"`.

This will compile / execute the above example file.

```
$ tsc compile.ts --moduleResolution Node && node compile.js
```

There is also some [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API).

Comment: How will this handle `import x from './relative/path'` and such, is there a way to specify how its imports work?

Comment: @Lance You may want to reach for something other than this method if you want to bundle or check types across files. As for how it handles imports that will entirely depend on the options you pass in. For instance, the default in the method now is to use CommonJS, so imports will be transformed into `require()` calls. Note: the imported module would neither be bundled nor compiled by default.