# Ultimate JS module solution for UMD with dependencies?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, amd, commonjs

I maintain and collaborate on some JavaScript modules written in CommonJS that are in need of high-quality UMD wrappers.

The dependencies are sourced from `npm` but have at least CommonJS and AMD support (or I can add it).

The CommonJS version goes on `npm` The UMD wrapped module will be pushed to `bower`

The wrapper must work in browsers (AMD + globals), and in Node.js (any and other CommonJS systems if possible). Any automation should preferably happen using Grunt (I'm pretty handy in grunt).

I've spend ages trawling Google en SO but it is a huge mess.

Some hopeful ones that don't quite cut it (or I am missing something, which is entirely possible):

- browserify
- gluejs
- grunt-umd

I'm finding desperate constructs like this everywhere: http://rathercurio.us/building-umd-modules-with-dependencies-with-browserify , but I'm not really cool with such hackery.

Any good tips on this? I'll take any pointer or link or tip.

Edit: clarification: that last thing said, the ideal solution should not require us to assemble chunks of boilerplate template code by hand and create new bugs. I cool with configuring and specifying stuff though.

Answer (score 2):

Your 1st and last stop should be [urequire.org](http://uRequire.org), the Universal Module Converter that does much more that just converting CommonJS and AMD javascript modules to UMD (or AMD or CommonJS or a standalone  using rjs/almond).

It allows you to manipulate Module's code and dependencies while converting: inject, replace or remove code and dependencies, export to global objects (`window`) or your bundle, inject & optionally merge common code (like initializations), add runtime information, minify and much much more.

Most of that using simple but hugely powerful declarations & optionally callbacks for fine grained manipulation. It works with standalone config files  (`.js`, `.coffee`, `.json`, `.yml` etc) and as-is as a [gruntjs config](https://github.com/aearly/grunt-urequire)

uRequire compiles from source modules written in javascript, coffeescript, livescriped, coco & icedcoffeescript without any plugins.

Forget boilerplate, code ceremony and repeating requires. The conversion templates are based on the well known [UMDjs](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) but can be customized via declarations to hide or provide functionality.

uRequire is opensource, MIT license and [hosted on github](https://github.com/anodynos/uRequire) and authored by me :-)

Comment: http://urequire.org/ makes some bold claims :) but assuming it delivers it could very well be the One. Do you also support source-maps (including converting/merging?) I use TypeScript and `grunt_concat_sourcemap` a lot (both generate maps) and would of course prefer to debug the original source even after urequire-ing them into AMD.

Comment: Well, try for your self if it delivers :-) uRequire started as a pet project for simple converting AMD-to-UMD, but many features were added since then transforming  it into a a tool that can perform 90% of the common tasks one can find in a typical gruntfile, with only [10% of the effort and boilerplate](http://urequire.org/masterdefaultsconfig.coffee#examples). Unfortunately sourcemaps and TypeScript are two features its not yet touching, but should :-(

Comment: I really like the UMD capabilities, it is very cool tech. Only I'd always favour to use my own choice of (typescript) compiler (here grunt-ts) for a power-user a specific one will have more features then a generic bundled version ("do one thing and do it well"). But sourcemap generation (and transformation) is pretty much a need-to-have these days. How else would we debug generated code? By manually doing lookups from bundle through whatever pipeline we used to get there? That is so 2010 :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree sourcemaps are very hot and unfortunately I dont have the time to implement them in urequire, although I would love to have them baked in sometime in the future. The same goes for typescript, [because of its bundling of deps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965572/compile-a-typescript-string-to-a-javascript-string-programmatically/17966246). I suppose if you have well written tests (and a type system:-) you shouldn't *need* to next-next-next so much against the source :-)

Comment: @AgelosPikoulas any news on source maps?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I'm afraid nothing yet :-/ Perhaps someone could provide a PR or something - uRequire uses the well known esprima AST parser and escodegen AST-to-code generator.