# Type-check a string of TypeScript code

Tags: typescript

**My situation:**

- I have a library containing type information for API responses. (eg: fetching a user object returns an object with `{ id: number, name: string }`).
- I want to validate that I've written my types correctly, and to catch any problems if the API changes.

**What I've done so far:**

I have a program which generates some TypeScript code, basically pulling data from the api and then seeing if the TypeScript compiler agrees that it matches the interface.

The result in the end looks something like:

```
import { User } from './user';

function verify<T>(data: T) {}

verify<User>({ id: 123, name: 'Joe' });
verify<User>({ id: 123, name: 17 }); // <-- obviously, this should give an error
```

Generating this code is all done, however I now need to get the compiler to type check it. I've been digging about in the typescript compiler API for a while and keep getting stuck because all of the functions which seem to do what I need all take a file name (ie: a path on disk) rather than a string of code. I understand that because of references to other files, there needs to be a path associated with the code, but I can't find any way to pass that in.

I'd like to avoid having to write these files to disk because

a) it seems a bit silly, since it's just going to be read from the disk then
b) it will likely get pretty messy in the source files, or I'd have to put it in a separate folder and then also rewrite all the import statements.

The TL;DR of my question is:

**Is there a way to type-check a string of TypeScript code?**

Comment: I believe you'd have to hook into the [TypeScript Language Service](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Language-Service-API).

Comment: Specifically, "For users who do not want to opt into incremental parsing, use `ts.ScriptSnapshot.fromString()`"

Comment: @SeanVieira ok, but then what? I have a snapshot... and?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan That page has a lot of high level information, but no examples of how to actually use the Language Service. Halp?

Comment: Sorry, I've never actually done anything with it. But that's where I would think you could get a string type-checked. Might look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/17965572/215552, where there's talk of a TypeScript API, but I'm not sure how current it is. There's also [this project on GitHub](https://github.com/teppeis/typescript-simple), but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions

## Don't have to write the js to disk just to run ts

> I'd like to avoid having to write these files to disk because

You can use `ts-node` : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node

## Check a string of js

A *string* of JS is easy to check. Just use `ts.transpile` from the compiler API. That said ... *you don't want to check just a string of js*. You want to check a set of *files*. Hence recommend just using ts-node.